# Meteor + React Error Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: meteor, reactjs

**I simplified my code for this question**

My project has these two files:

Comments.jsx

```
Comments = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        Hello Comments
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

App.jsx

```
App = React.createClass({

  renderComments() {
    return <Comments />;
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {this.renderComments()}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

When I run the project, I get the error below:

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined,
>   boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a
>   ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of
>   `App`
>
> Exception in callback of async function: Error: Invariant Violation:
>   Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check
>   the render method of `App`.

If I remove `{this.renderComments()}` from App.jsx `render()` jsx mark up everything works again.

What did I do wrong?  Why can't I embed a `<Comments />` ?

---

**Additional info**

Ok this is really weird. If I rename all instances of `Comments` to `Commnt`, `comments` to `commnts`, and rename the file Comments.jsx to `Commnt.jsx`, then **everything works!!!**.  I tried renaming it to anything else it works.  I only get this error when I use the word Comments.  I have to start driving, so i'll look up later if Comments is a reserved word or something.

I don't have any other files in my meteorjs project other than an html file and a `myhelloworld.jsx` which has 2 url routes.  So I'm prety sure I know for a fact i didn't use Comments anywhere else.

Comment: Do you use any module system? require.js, es6 modules, etc? My guess is you shoule export `Comments` from Comments.jsx and then import it in App.jsx

Comment: I'm not sure.  When I first created this meteor project, i just did `meteor add react; meteor add iron:router; meteor remove autopublish;`. Those are the only things I did prior to starting this basic app.

Comment: Yeah but how does `App.jsx` know there's a `Comments` object in your project? It probably doesn't know sot it's `undefined`. Try moving the definition of `Comments` to the App.jsx and it should work. Sorry I can't help you with the way meteor.js manages importing/exporting code between files.

Comment: I created a fiddle and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/emadb/69z2wepo/25414/

Comment: Hi pawal, ema, I got things to work by using a word other than `Comments`.  i updated my question with these details.

Comment: Oh wait, maybe because in my meteor project, I already use a variable called `Comments` which is a database collection object.  Maybe naming conflict? I'll have to check later once I'm back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this in my mainproject.jsx of my meteor project `Comments = new Mongo.Collection("comments");` . So this caused a naming conflict because meteor pushes this variable to both the server and client.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this problem.

Just NEVER COPY OR DRAG any file from another place to the meteor filesystem.

First create the file, then you are free to paste the code you'd like inside.